# ¿Cómo puedo hacer este código más corto?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito que le siguiente código sea de una sola linea, es decir, una solución más corta.

```
 function alive(playerName, points){
   if(playerName == "ikk" && points > 30 || playerName == "gut" && points > 10){
    console.log(true);
}
else{
    console.log(false);
}
 }

alive("gut", 35);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué lo necesitas? Normalmene lo importante es que esté bien estructurado y sea legible, la brevedad es aconsejable pero no debería lo único importante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las condiciones `if` devuelven un booleano dependiendo de si la condición se cumple o no. En tu caso

```
if(playerName == "ikk" && points > 30 || playerName == "gut" && points > 10)
```

Puede devolver tanto un valor `true` si todas las condiciones se cumplen o un `false` en caso de que algo falle.

Como bien mencionaron en otra respuesta tu función podría retornar el valor del if

```
 return playerName == "ikk" && points > 30 || playerName == "gut" && points > 10;
```

Así que cuando mandes llamar la función podría devolver un `true` o un `false`.

```
alive("gut", 35); // Devuelve un true o un false.
```

Podrías hacer uso de los `console.log` de dos maneras:

Dentro de tu misma función:

```
function alive(playerName, points){
  console.log(playerName == "ikk" && points > 30 || playerName == "gut" && points > 10); // Console.log de un true o un false dependiendo
             // si las condiciones se cumplen o no
}
```

O utilizando el valor retornado por tu función:

```
function alive(playerName, points){
 return(playerName == "ikk" && points > 30 || playerName == "gut" && points > 10); // Devuelve un true o false
 }

 console.log(alive("gut", 35)); // Ejecuta la función, obtiene un valor y lo imprime en consola.
```

Me parece que la mejor opción es que la función retorne un valor booleano y manejes los mensajes dependiendo el resultado que arroja tu función.

Answer (score 4):

No hagas booleano algo que ya es booleano

```
 function alive(playerName, points){
   return playerName == "ikk" && points > 30 || playerName == "gut" && points > 10;
}
```

Comment: quite la mia por que estaba mal en la comparacion de puntos :)

Comment: Disculpa, me podrías explicar un poco. Apenas estoy entrando en le mundo de JS :)

Answer (score 0):

Usando funciones flecha no es necesario ni `return` ni corchetes ni la palabra `function` si la respuesta tiene una sola línea, como este caso.

```js
var alive = (playerName, points)=>playerName=="ikk"&&points>30||playerName=="gut"&&points>10
  
console.log(alive("gut", 35));
```